# How to get the elements from a table after all components are rendered in React / testing-library/react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test my UsersTable page in React, but the testing library gets the elements before they have time to render.
Please check my code below:

**UsersTable.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
import { fetchUsers } from 'api';


function UsersTable() {
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getUsers = async () => {
            const data = await fetchUsers();
            setUsers(data);
        };

        getUsers();
    }, []);


    const renderUsers = () => users.map((user) => {
        const { id, fullName, email } = user;

        return (
            <tr key={ id } >
                <td>
                    <Link to={ `user/${id}` }>{ fullName }</Link>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <Link to={ `user/${id}/mail` }>{ email }</Link>
                </td>
            </tr>
        );
    });
    return (
        <div data-testid='userTest' className="users-table">
            <h1>Users</h1>
            <Table striped borderless>
                <thead>
                    <tr style={{
                            borderBottom: "1px solid #cccccc"
                        }}> 
                        <th>User</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    { renderUsers() }
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </div>
    );
}

export default UsersTable;
```

**userTable.test.js**

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import UserTable from '../components/users/UserTable';




test("Test #1: Count Users", async () => {

    const component = render(
        <Router>
            <UserTable />
        </Router>
    );

    const users = component.getByTestId('userTest')
    expect(users.querySelectorAll('tr').length).toBe(193)
})
```

**Note**: `<Router>` prevents the error `Error: Uncaught [Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>`

**Expect:** Expecting to have 192 users + 1 row containing `thead`, but instead I get 1 row containing only the `thead`.

Comment: See https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/

Comment: Are you mocking your `fetchusers`? What you need to garantee its that the component is rendered the table with rows and cells, not the number of td chids... Take a look in what you should avoid with testing library [here](https://testing-library.com/docs/#what-you-should-avoid-with-testing-library).

Comment: But if you want to test the number of `tr`, you should avoid use `selectors` like you did. The proper way in this case would be `const trElements = screen.getAllByRole('row')` and `expect(trElements).toHaveLength(193)`

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Luis. I ended up testing that the components are rendered and tested some user inputs. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
expect(getByTestId('userTest').children.length).toBe(193);
```